# How to put another line of text immediately after another line of text?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to place a line of text immediately after another line of text, however react-native is creating a lot of unneeded space between the two. I think this may be because of the top line's big font size.

I am trying to get my application to look like this
[image]

However, my page looks like this. Notice there is a large gap between the number and "Total Vehicle".
[image]

Here's my source code I tried using paddingBottom for the second line of text, but that did not end up working.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = { () => alert('hello')}>
    <ImageBackground style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} source={require('../cars.jpg')} >
         <View style = {{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',flex:1, paddingBottom:15}}>
             <Text style = {{color:'#E31E24', fontSize:120}}> {this.props.total} </Text>
             <Text style = {{color:'white'}}> TOTAL VEHICLE </Text>
         </View>
    </ImageBackground>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lineHeight or marginTop(negetive) in the style of second text to move up that.
i wish it work for you.